# Стоит ли создавать header с include-ами?

Tags: c++, ооп

Если проект разбит на множество файлов, описывающих разных наследников некоторого абстрактного класса, то в файле, в котором нужно использовать всех этих наследников будет много include-ов в начале.

Стоит ли создать ещё один header, внутри которого будет просто список include-ов всех этих наследников и подключать уже его?

Или может стоит перенести всех наследников в тот же файл, где описан и абстрактный класс-родитель?

Или оставить как есть, с длинным списком include-ов в файле использующем всех наследников? 
[image: Визуализация]

Comment: Все равно наследники без родителя не употребляются, поэтому можно создавать один большой хедер со всеми описаниями. Сейчас вообще, с развитием шаблонов, все больше кода перелезает в хедера.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 , но наследники могут употребляться по одному, например тестироваться, разбиение их на разные файлы делалось из этих соображений.

Comment: Все равно невозможно тестировать наследника, не включая в проект хедер родителя/родителей. Есть две тенденции. Один большой хедер удобен тем, что он один и его не забудешь. Много маленьких хедеров удобны тем, что их проще листать и править поодиночке. Но на мой вкус мотаться внутри одного хедера проще, чем мотаться между кучей хедеров хотя бы потому, что не надо переключать вкладки на IDE, а можно обойтись поиском и кнопками навигации. Так что это только вопрос вкуса и темперамента каждого конкретного программиста.

Comment: Стоит то или иное решение, зависит от  задачи.  Следить нужно за тем, чтобы каждая модуль отражала собранные вместе логически  связанные сущности.  Нет никакого однозначнего ответа

Comment: Переносить наследников точно не нужно. Если инклюдники вместе в одном классе нужны только в Duck.hpp, то стоит просто включить все инклюдники. Если там код уровня `AllDucks* duck; switch duck_type: {case "wooden": duck = new WoddenDuck; break; case... }`, а дальше вызываешь обстрактные методы AllDucks, то хорошей идеей будет использовать шаблон проэктирлвания фабрика. Вынести выбор, какой класс создавать, в отдельный класс. И в сpp фабрики заинклюдить наследников Duck. Иначе как глазу милее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

имхо, не стоит создавать ни отдельный хидер, ни, тем более, включать наследников к абстрактному классу. Если первое - это просто ещё один файл, который нужен всего лишь для того, чтобы в cpp сделать один инклюд вместо нескольких, то во втором сразу две проблемы: 1) абстрактный класс на то и абстрактный класс, что ему не нужно знать ни о каких наследниках, это, по сути, просто интерфейс; 2) это может существенно отразится на времени компиляции, ведь каждый инклюд добавляется в cpp целиком препроцессором вместе со всеми включенными в него инклюдами. Поэтому, имхо, хороший тон - это включение только необходимых хидеров в cpp файл, а в хидерах, по возможности, использовать предекларацию.

Comment: Как выбрать коллектив для фирмы?... На такой вопрос можно ответить только после предварительных конкретизаций. То же самое и здесь, и я не согласен ни с одним однозначным ответом

Comment: @ARHovsepyan специально для вас впереди каждого "однозначного" ответа стоит имхо. Ну кроме того, что использование хидеров вместо предекларацию (где это возможно) замедляет компиляцию - с этим, я думаю, никто спорить не будет.

Comment: специально для вас_ абреввиатура имхо означает  In My Humble Opinion (по моему скромному мнению). Это означает, что вы думаете, что так нужно поступать всегда, а я всего лишь ответил, что категорически не согласен с этим... На этом все.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan это означает, что МОЕ ЛИЧНОЕ МНЕНИЕ и вы могли бы не утруждать ни себя ни меня не соглашаясь с ним.